# PostgreSQL Invalid Syntax

Tags: postgresql

I have this in the where clause of my SQL query:

'2023/10/21 14:46:32.805068000' + interval '1 second'

This causes me to have an "invalid input syntax for type interval" error.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: You need to cast the string. `select '2023/10/21 14:46:32.805068000'::timestamptz + interval '1 second';` or `timestamp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a timestamp datatype to calculate .

```
SELECT '2023/10/21 14:46:32.805068000'::timestamp + interval '1 second'
```

| ?column? |
| --- |
| 2023-10-21 14:46:33.805068 |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/t2oEPspA)

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell PostgreSQL that the first string is a timestamp

```sql
timestamp '2023/10/21 14:46:32.805068000' + interval '1 second'
```

If you don't PostgreSQL tries to guess, and assumes you are adding 2 values with the same type (2 intervals).